# Map based on Leaflet and AngularJS not loaded correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, matplotlib-basemap

My map based on Leaflet and AngularJS is not loading correctly. I do not know what's going on but the maps tiles are not laid out as they should be.

This is the base map:

[image: base map]

This is my code:

```
    function setMapPosition(){
        $scope.center = {
            lat: 51.505,
                lng: -0.09,
                zoom: 8
        };


        $scope.defaults= {
            scrollWheelZoom: false
        };

        $scope.tiles = 'openstreetmap';
    }
```

Comment: http://djonatas.com.br/img0001.png

Comment: <leaflet center="center" tiles="tiles" defaults="defaults" width="100%" height="480px"></leaflet>

Comment: Where is the code that actually inits the map? Which library are you using combining Leaflet and Angular. If none, you'll need to provide your code that is drawing the map in the first place.

Answer (score 7):

This problem often occurs due to resizing of any parent container while the map is already initialized.

In order to tell the map that there was a resize you can call `map.invalidateSize();`.

It could also be that you didn't resize any parent container manually, then a possible solution would be to call `map.invalidateSize();` after your document is ready.

To do this with the [angular-leaflet-directive](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive) try the following inside your controller which injects `leafletData`.:

```
leafletData.getMap().then(function(map) {
    map.invalidateSize(false);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using leaflet directive for angularjs then

Check if your map container has an `ng-cloak` attribute. If it's there remove it.

***Map not loading when ng-cloak presents***

```
<div class="map-container" ng-cloak>
<leaflet class="map-container" markers="markers" lf-center="center" width="100%">
</leaflet>
</div>
```

***Map is loading when ng-cloak is not present***

```
<div class="map-container">
  <leaflet class="map-container" markers="markers" lf-center="center" width="100%">
  </leaflet>
</div>
```